# document db - denormalized references - best practice

Tags: design-patterns, ravendb, document-database

Yo - this is not a ravendb issue per se - it's another design question
pertaining to document dbs in general.

So I've been using DenormalizedReference quite a bit and it has
just occured to me that in a lot of places this makes DDD rather hard.

So, say for instance i have an object that has a child collection:

```
 List<DenormalizedReference<SomeType>>
```

This child collection is created when the parent is instanciated with
an overloaded constructor accepting a `List<SomeOtherType>`

now - in the ctor i'd like to create this list from the SomeOtherType
collection being passed in - which means i will need to create a new
SomeType for each SomeOtherType.

Without passing in the DocumentSession into my domain - which i'm not
going to do - this wont work because when the parent AR is saved we
lose the properties on each child object except for Id and Name

How is everyone else handling this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.
Or rather, you shouldn't do that.

There are several ways to resolve this, usually using a static gateway to get the session, but the problem is that this approach creates a lazy loaded collection, with all the problems that this have.

RavenDB was specifically designed to avoid this sort of issues. And you can include items to avoid going back to the server, but you shouldn't try to move between ids and types transparently like that.

Comment: So using Includes is the best way of achieving what i need? I think that i'm not really using RavenDb to it's potential by clinging on to some relational concepts. the real value is achieved when you go the full ddd/cqrs route for a larger domain at least. would you agree with that?

Comment: Yes & no.
This really depends on what sort of env you have and how you use it.
Includes & ids are one way to solve the references issue, denormalized references are another. They have different cost/benefit ratios, depending on what we are doing and how we use things